# Adding different Greek characters to individual axis tick labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, labels, greek, ticks

I've been scouring the web and the pgfplots manual trying to find an example of labelling different x-axis ticks with different Greek characters.
The closest i've found is using

```
    xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\sigma $},
    xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
```

My full code for the plot is as follows

```
    \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        title={Standard Normal Distribution $Z\sim N\left ( 0,1 \right )$},
        xlabel={$z$-score},
        ylabel={Probability},
        xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\sigma $},
        xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
        ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4},
        ymax=0.5
        ]

        \newcommand\MU{0}
        \newcommand\SIGMA{1}
        \addplot[
            domain=-4*\SIGMA:4*\SIGMA,
            samples=201,
            ]
            {exp(-(x-\MU)^2 / 2 / \SIGMA^2) / (\SIGMA * sqrt(2*pi))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

But here it obviously just amends each xtick with a sigma next to the value.
What I want is for the xticks to read mu-3*sigma, mu-2*sigma, mu-sigma, mu etc etc.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    title={Standard Normal Distribution $Z\sim N\left ( 0,1 \right )$},
    xlabel={$z$-score},
    ylabel={Probability},
    xticklabel={$\mu\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytick}{int(\tick)}
    \ifnum\mytick=0
    \else
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\tick<0,"","+")}
    \pgfmathresult\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\sigma\fi $},
    xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4},
    ymax=0.5
    ]

    \newcommand\MU{0}
    \newcommand\SIGMA{1}
    \addplot[
        domain=-4*\SIGMA:4*\SIGMA,
        samples=201,
        ]
        {exp(-(x-\MU)^2 / 2 / \SIGMA^2) / (\SIGMA * sqrt(2*pi))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I made the plot a bit wider such that the now wider labels do not overlap. Alternatively, you may rotate them.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks very much. For future reference, should I want to, is there a way of creating completely unique tick labels that have no pattern, so they're completely bespoke but whilst still using greek characters?

Comment: @AntonyStanley-Clarke Could you please try to reword your comment? I have a hard time figuring out what you're after. (Of course you could add a list of symbols to `xticklabel`, is that what you want?)

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguous comment. Yes, adding symbols to xticklabel is what I'm after. I wasn't aware that it was possible. I'm completely new to LaTeX and all I have seen/explored is choosing the xticks as I have done above. This only seems to accept numeric characters. I assume there is another way to choose which xticks to print but also give them bespoke characters?